# Change "Via" Name In DocuSign Envelope Email

Tags: node.js

Currently using the DocuSign nodejs documentation to send Envelope to a user who fills out an online form. However the email that comes back from Docusign sending looks like this...

**Andrew Stanton via DocuSign dse_NA3@docusign.net**

However I want to adjust this to look like it comes from business instead of the name of the owner of the DocuSign account. Something like this...

**BUSINESS NAME via DocuSign <dse_NA3@docusign.net**

Is this an option that is available to set within the docusign node js package? This is how I currently have my nodejs code setup...

```js
/**
 * Creating Docusign Envelope
 *
 * @param pdfPath = Document getting sent for signing
 * @param email
 * @param firstName
 * @param lastName
 */
export async function sendEnvelope(pdfPath, email, firstName, lastName) {

  // Signer Information:
  const signerName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  const signerEmail = email;

  /**
   *  The envelope is sent to the provided email address.
   *  One signHere tab is added.
   *  The document path supplied is relative to the working directory
   */
  const apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  const { basePath, accessToken } = await getAuthInfo();
  apiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
  apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

  // Set the DocuSign SDK components to use the apiClient object
  docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);

  // Create the envelope request
  const envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();

  //Set the Email Subject line and email message
  envDef.emailSubject =
    "Please sign this contract with BUSINESS NAME.";
  envDef.emailBlurb =
    "Thank you for providing your listing with Dade Auctions Incorporated. Please sign this contract.";

  // Read the file from the document and convert it to a Base64String
  const pdfBytes = fs.readFileSync(pdfPath),
    pdfBase64 = pdfBytes.toString("base64");

  // Create the document request object
  const doc = docusign.Document.constructFromObject({
    documentBase64: pdfBase64,
    fileExtension: "pdf", // You can send other types of documents too.
    name: "DADE Auctions Listing Agreement",
    documentId: "1",
  });

  // Create a documents object array for the envelope definition and add the doc object
  envDef.documents = [doc];

  // Create the signer object with the previously provided name / email address
  const signer = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    name: signerName,
    email: signerEmail,
    routingOrder: "1",
    recipientId: "1",
  });

  // Create the signHere tab to be placed on the envelope
  const signHere = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    documentId: "1",
    recipientId: "1",
    tabLabel: "SignHereTab",
    anchorString: "Seller (Sign Here)",
    anchorXOffset: "-30",
    anchorYOffset: "-20",
    anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: "false",
    anchorUnits: "pixels",
  });

  const signerDate = docusign.DateSigned.constructFromObject({
    recipientId: "1",
    anchorString: "Seller (Sign Here)",
    anchorXOffset: "45",
    anchorYOffset: "20",
  });

  const initialHere = docusign.InitialHere.constructFromObject({
    documentId: "1",
    recipientId: "1",
    tabLabel: "SignHereTab",
    anchorString: "Initial:",
    anchorXOffset: "45",
    anchorYOffset: "0",
    anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: "false",
    anchorUnits: "pixels",
  });

  // Create the overall tabs object for the signer and add the signHere tabs array
  // Note that tabs are relative to receipients/signers.
  signer.tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    signHereTabs: [signHere],
    initialHereTabs: [initialHere],
    dateSignedTabs: [signerDate],
  });


  // Add the recipients object to the envelope definition.
  // It includes an array of the signer objects.
  envDef.recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    signers: [signer], //dadeSigner removed
  });
  // Set the Envelope status. For drafts, use 'created' To send the envelope right away, use 'sent'
  envDef.status = "sent";

  // Send the envelope
  // The SDK operations are asynchronous, and take callback functions.
  const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
  const createEnvelopePromise = promisify(envelopesApi.createEnvelope).bind(
    envelopesApi
  );
  let results = undefined;

  try {
    results = await createEnvelopePromise(ACCOUNT_ID, {
      envelopeDefinition: envDef,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("An exception occurred.", e);
    const body = e.response && e.response.body;
    if (body) {
      return { body, status: e.response.status };
    } else {
      // Not a DocuSign exception
      throw e;
    }
  }
  // Envelope has been created:
  if (results) {
    return { body: results, signerName, signerEmail };
  }

  return null;
}
```

Any help on how to switch the name of the From email address that gets automatically sent would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The name and email address corresponding to the sending DocuSign user account will always be shown on/for sent envelopes. You can setup multiple users within your DocuSign account and choose which one you use when authenticating and that will be used for the sender name/email address values.

You could setup a [Service Auth / JWT impersonation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-best-practice/) unless the person who you would like to be listed as the sender is present to authenticate themselves for Auth Code Grant.